# Android emulator screen

Tags: android, eclipse, screen, emulation

It was an interesting thing. Android emulator screen was 4 pieces. Why it happened? There are examples in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was in "Edit Android Virtual Device" setting that I chose "USe Host GPU". 
Fix the end.

[image]